# Changing Android activity name in Cordova config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity

I have an old Android Cordova app whose manifest has `<activity android:name=".MyActivity"`. This has already been published to the Play store, so I [can no longer change the name](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nm).

I'm trying to migrate to the Cordova CLI workflow, but the Android app it generates has `android:name="MainActivity"`. How can I customize this in config.xml, so it generates the right name?

I found an undocumented preference "android-activityName". I tried setting this to ".MyActivity", and removing/adding the android platform. But with this setting, it no longer created the activity class at all, and I got an error "Error: No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity".

Comment: I think its problem of Package name instead of activity name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this using the [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin, adding this to my config.xml:

```
<custom-preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:name" value=".MyActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also faced a similar situation.What I did was I changed the id of the widget tag inside config.xml to reflect the package name where I put my **MyActivity** class which extends **CordovaActivity**.Make sure you have deleted the unwanted **MainActivity** class that cordova generates(if you are putting your MyActivity class in the same package as MainActivity class).**And also your MyActivity class should be extending CordovaActivity (important)**.Then open config.xml and change the widget tag as given below.

```
//Change the id value to the package name where you put your MyActivity class
<widget id="com.yourCompanyName.yourPackageName" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

After doing this clean the project using **cordova clean** command and then rebuild the project.Additionally you can use **android-packageName** property to widget tag to give android specific package name and **ios-CFBundleIdentifier** for ios specific name.

Comment: This is not for changing activity name. This is for changing package name.

Comment: @Hardik Vaghani By default when you create a new cordova project by CLI you get an activity called MainActivity which extends CordovaActivity ,the OP said he used a different name for his activity so he needs cordova to find his MyActivity as the main activity.I have answered just for that ,delete the unwanted MainActivity that cordova generates,let him put his MyActivity class(make sure MyActivity extends CordovaActivity) in the same package or different package put that package name as the widget id value,clean the project and rebuild :)

Comment: @Hardik Vaghani I think the title is little bit confusing :)

Comment: I think that the simplest solution is to use a [cordova hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/) (eg. **after_platform_add** ) replacing the `MainActivity.java` with your custom `MainActivity.java`

Comment: It is important to note that if you change the package name, run the `cordova clean` command, and build your project again, the `MainActivity.java` file will get deleted because the `platforms/android/app/src/main/java/<package/name/path>` folder gets removed. This will then cause the "No Java files found which extend CordovaActivity" error on subsequent builds. Either save this Java file somewhere else (or use your own) and replace it to enable builds again. Removing and adding the android platform again will also restore it (not great if you are customizing your build process, though.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this was my solution in bash. I had the wrong Activity name and the wrong java file name, so I needed to change both.

I created the following `bash` function:
First I replace all `MainActivity` references with `NewActivityName`.
Then I look for the java file and rename it.

```
function rename_the_activity {
    platformDir="/path/to/platformdir"
    grep -rl 'MainActivity' $platformDir | sort | uniq | xargs perl -e "s/MainActivity/NewActivityName/" -pi
    activity=$(find $platformDir -name 'MainActivity.java')
    newactivity="${activity/MainActivity/NewActivityName}"
    mv $activity $newactivity
    print_blue "Renamed activity class MainActivity to NewActivityName"
}
```